# fuzzy string matching for common multi-character OCR errors in python

Tags: python, ocr, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-comparison

I'm trying to do some fuzzy matching on some OCR results, and I want to be able to factor in common OCR errors.  In particular, I'm matching streets to a database of streets.  I figured out how to down-weight common single-character substitution errors using the weighted-levenshtein package, but it seems to only work on single characters, when many of the most common errors are things like "li" to "h".

Right now, "Mam" matches most closely to "MAY ST," when I'd really like it to match to "MAIN ST" instead.  I'd like to be able to build something in that knows that "IN" and "M" often correspond because "in" gets read as "m" by the OCR.

Here's the current code I'm working with (I'm down-weighting inserts because some of the streets I'm working with are abbreviated or missing "St", "Ave", etc.):

```
import numpy as np
from weighted_levenshtein import lev, osa, dam_lev

def lratio(str1,str2):
    insert_costs = 0.5*np.ones(128, dtype=np.float64)
    delete_costs = np.ones(128, dtype=np.float64)
    substitute_costs = np.ones((128, 128), dtype=np.float64)
    substitute_costs[ord('O'), ord('0')] = 0.25
    substitute_costs[ord('0'), ord('O')] = 0.25
    substitute_costs[ord('I'), ord('T')] = 0.5
    substitute_costs[ord('T'), ord('I')] = 0.5
    ldistance = lev(str1, str2, insert_costs=insert_costs, delete_costs=delete_costs, substitute_costs=substitute_costs)
    return (1.0 - float(ldistance) / float(len(str1) + len(str2))) * 100.0
```

I don't think there's a way to modify weighted-levenshtein for multi-character substitution.  But if there were, it would be great.  And I bet there's a package out there that has this capacity--possibly a package that has a library of common errors already built in.

Any ideas?